# Вывод картинки при нажатии в обратной форме

Tags: css

Есть список radio button, надо при нажатии выводить картинку. 
[image: Вот так сейчас]

Вот так нужно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Главное, чтобы картинка выходила за поля `<ul>`.
Помогите пожалуйста.

```css
p,
h3 {
  margin: 7px 0;
}
label {
  vertical-align: top;
}
h3.btn {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px
}
ul.mainform1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.21);
}
ul.mainform1 > li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 45px 0;
}
[id^=r-] {
  display: none;
}
[id^=r-] + label {
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 1px #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-height: 140px;
}
[id^=r-] + label .i {
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
[id^=r-] + label h3 {
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
[id^=r-] + label .h3-unsure {
  display: none;
}
[id^=r-]:checked + ul li {
  display: block;
  background: url(http://a0013169.xsph.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/unsure.png);
  background-position: center;
  color: #fff;
}
[id^=r-]:checked + label .i,
[id^=r-]:checked + label p {
  display: none;
}
[id^=r-]:checked + label h3 {
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}
[id^=r-]:checked + label h3.btn {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  display: none;
}
[id^=r-]:checked + label .h3-unsure {
  display: none;
}
span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap .wpcf7-text {
  width: 80%;
}
.column_column ul {
  margin: 0 0 0 30px;
  line-height: 21px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mainform1">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="r-1" name="r" />
    <label for="r-1" style="border-right: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.48);;">
      <span class="i"><img src="http://a0013169.xsph.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/car7.png"></span>
      <p>Car</p>
      <h3 class="h3-unsure">Unsure?</h3>
      <h3 class="btn">Select</h3>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="r-2" name="r" />
    <label for="r-2" style="border-right: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.48);;">
      <span class="i"><img src="http://a0013169.xsph.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/van7.png"></span>
      <p>Car</p>
      <h3 class="h3-unsure">Unsure?</h3>
      <h3 class="btn">Select</h3>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="r-3" name="r" />
    <label for="r-3" style="border-right: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.48);;">
      <span class="i"><img src="http://a0013169.xsph.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/car7.png"></span>
      <p>Car</p>
      <h3 class="h3-unsure">Unsure?</h3>
      <h3 class="btn">Select</h3>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="r-4" name="r" />
    <label for="r-4" style="border-right: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.48);;">
      <span class="i"><img src="http://a0013169.xsph.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/truck7.png"></span>
      <p>Car</p>
      <h3 class="h3-unsure">Unsure?</h3>
      <h3 class="btn">Select</h3>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="r-5" name="r" />
    <label for="r-5">
      <span class="i"><img src="http://a0013169.xsph.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/suv7.png"></span>
      <p>Car</p>
      <h3 class="h3-unsure">Unsure?</h3>
      <h3 class="btn">Select</h3>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: HTML и CSS приведите... и еще, не очень ясно, что значит "картинка выходила за поля"? Какая картинка, какие поля?

Comment: @cyadvert добавил код в Шапку

Comment: Код, это хорошо. Но все-таки подробней объясните, что должно происходить и в какой момент? Вакм надо, чтобы машинка пропадала, и вместо нее появлялся текст?

Comment: `+` - в css - выбирает следующий элемент, за инпутом у вас только лабел идет. никаких _ul li_

Comment: @cyadvert при нажатии надо, чтобы пропадала иконка и был текст с фоном синим, в принципе это было уже сделано, но не смог сделать размер этого выбора больше чем ячейка, как на картинке.

Answer (score 1):

Может тебе подойдет такой вариант оформления: http://jsfiddle.net/wk904jrb/  его придется немного переделать, если тебе нужны именно `radio button`, но для примера, думаю тебе поможет.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".checklist .checkbox-select").click(
     function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
       $(this).parent().find(":checkbox").attr("checked", "checked");

     }
   );

   $(".checklist .checkbox-deselect").click(
     function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $(this).parent().removeClass("selected");
       $(this).parent().find(":checkbox").removeAttr("checked");

     }
   );

 });
```

```css
body {
  font: 12px/1.3"Lucida Grande", "Lucida", "Arial", Sans-serif;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 17px;
}
fieldset {
  border: 0;
}
.checklist {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.checklist li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: url(http://i10.pixs.ru/storage/4/9/0/checkboxbg_5279710_19877490.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
  width: 105px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  font: normal 11px/1.3"Lucida Grande", "Lucida", "Arial", Sans-serif;
}
.checklist li.selected {
  background-position: -105px 0;
}
.checklist li.selected .checkbox-select {
  display: none;
}
.checkbox-select {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 118px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 85px;
  height: 23px;
  background: url(http://i9.pixs.ru/storage/5/0/0/selectgif_5090996_19877500.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
.checklist li input {
  display: none;
}
a.checkbox-deselect {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  right: 10px;
}
.checklist li.selected a.checkbox-deselect {
  display: block;
}
.checklist li p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}
.sendit {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  top: 118px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 115px;
  height: 34px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(http://i10.pixs.ru/storage/5/0/3/senditgif_8513494_19877503.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="choices">
      <h4>Оригинальные checkbox</h4>
      <ul class="checklist">
        <li>
          <input name="jqdemo" value="value1" type="checkbox" />
          <p>Первая секция</p>
          <a class="checkbox-select" href="#">Select</a>
          <a class="checkbox-deselect" href="#">Cancel</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input name="jqdemo" value="value2" type="checkbox" />
          <p>Вторая секция</p>
          <a class="checkbox-select" href="#">Select</a>
          <a class="checkbox-deselect" href="#">Cancel</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input name="jqdemo" value="value3" type="checkbox" />
          <p>Третья секция</p>
          <a class="checkbox-select" href="#">Select</a>
          <a class="checkbox-deselect" href="#">Cancel</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input name="jqdemo" value="value4" type="checkbox" />
          <p>Четверая секция</p>
          <a class="checkbox-select" href="#">Select</a>
          <a class="checkbox-deselect" href="#">Cancel</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </label>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <button class="sendit" type="submit" name="submitbutton" title="Submit the form" />Send it!</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но это чекбокс, а надо все-таки радио. Но можно переписать конечно, правда это будет сложней, чем сейчас)